# SQL selecting with NULLS to variable

Tags: t-sql, variables, select

I have a variable where I want to select values from a table into a single nvarchar

```
Declare @Var nvarchar(max)
set @Var = ''
select @Var = @Var + CAST(Id as nvarchar(50)) + ' - ' + Name from Table
```

But if at least one of the rows in Table contains NULL in either Id or Name column the value of @Var will always be NULL

Is there a way to still select the values from the table if some of the values are NULL?

Like replacing the NULLs with some text or ignoring the rows that contain NULLs and selecting other rows?

Comment: You are looking for ISNULL(ID,'') --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 or just include a where statement <where id is not null>

Comment: That works. Thank you.

Comment: @EmmanouilKaramalegos you should post that as an answer.